# Firebase phone number authentication, code is expired every time

Tags: android, react-native

I have added firebase authentication in my application. It works fine if i add phone number of other user in my phone. But if i add mine phone number it sends OTP but when i enter that OTP every time it shows error "SMS code has expired".

Is there any auto authentication? Is there something that i missing?

I have used below code to send OTP

```
 firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(this.state.countryCode + this.state.phoneNumber)
            .then(confirmResult => {


                this.setState({
                    progressVisible: false
                })

                console.log("confirmResult is " + confirmResult)

                AsyncStorage.setItem('CountryCode', this.state.countryCode);
                AsyncStorage.setItem('PhoneNumber', this.state.phoneNumber);


                this.props.navigation.navigate("OtpScreen", {
                    confirmResult, isConnected: this.state.isConnected
                })
            })
```

I have used below code to verify OTP

```
 this.state.confirmResult.confirm(this.state.otpText)
                .then(user => {

                    // this.setState({
                    //     progressVisible: false
                    // })
                    console.log("Debug starts, 2");
                    this.hitAuthApi()

                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.setState({
                        progressVisible: false
                    })
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        Alert.alert("Error" + error);
                    }, 100)
                });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a firebase in-build listener for auto login, which need to initialise in component. It will automatically detect SMS in android.

```
this.unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            // alert(JSON.stringify(user))
            if (user) {


               //hit Api 
            } else {
                // User has been signed out, reset the state

            }
        });
```